# Pushing an array in a decremented for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an array of integers that I am attempting to reverse the indexes for.

For example I am attempting to make `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  =>  [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]`

I am approaching this issue with a for loop of the original array `firstArr`

```
reverseArr = []

for (i = 0; i > firstArr.length; i--) {
       reverseArr.push(firstArr[i])
}

console.log(reverseArr) // 0
```

When I console.log `reverseArr` my return value is 0. I'm new to javascript and i'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong

I am expecting `reverseArr` to hold the values of `firstArr` just in opposite order.

Comment: `i` should not start at 0 if you're counting down.

Comment: Try writing down the values of `i` as the loop progresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Array.prototype.reverse(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Note: it is reversing the actual array in place, so `firstArr.reverse()` will modify `firstArr` itself.

Answer (score 0):

According to your approach, you are trying to add items to reverseArr from the last items of firstArr. so for that you have to initialize `i = firstArr.length -1`  not with '0' and condition as `i >= 0`. Its because array index starts with '0' and the last index of array is length of array - 1.

```js
firstArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
reverseArr = []

for (i = firstArr.length-1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
       reverseArr.push(firstArr[i])
}

console.log(reverseArr)
```

You can also achieve this by using built in `reverse()` function as below:

```js
firstArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
reverseArr = firstArr.reverse()

console.log(reverseArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is messed up a little.
It should be as follows:

```
reverseArr = [];
for (i = firstArr.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
   reverseArr.push(firstArr[i]);
}
console.log(reverseArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript array **`reverse()`** method for this which reverses the order of the elements in an array:

Refer below example for better understanding:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array;

function printReverseArray() {
  array.reverse();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="printReverseArray()">Reverse</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```